# How can add windows media player to fmx delphi?

Tags: firemonkey, windows-media-player, tmediaplayer

I cannot add windows media player to my fmx project. I have only tmediaplayer but it does not support most extensions. Is there any way to add it from activex component? Thank you.

Comment: https://chapmanworld.com/windows-media-player-in-delphi/

Comment: not vlc I said firemonkey

Comment: I need more info from you. You can add TMediaPlayer to any fmx project but you would also need to add TMediaPlayerControl. And by extensions, do you mean .MP4 / MP3 etc? If that is so just download K_LITE_CODEC_PACK and install.